# Entity Field Query - Type of the Field

Tags: database

How do I determine the individual field type using an `EntityFieldQuery`?

Here is the sample code for extracting the fields of a content type named 'digital_iq_test_2012', which contains many fields. How do I determine the type of each field?

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'digital_iq_test_2012')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Any help?

Comment: To those people editing this question to make the uppercase 'I's into lower case 'i's...please stop it, this is an English speaking website and in English the 'I' must be capitalised :)

Answer (score 1):

`EntityFieldQuery` essentially just prepares an SQL query and gives you the results, it doesn't return any meta information about the fields themselves.

To get that you can use the [Field Info API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/group/field_info/7), e.g.

```
// Get all fields attached to your bundle.
$fields = field_info_instances('node', 'digital_iq_test_2012');

// Loop through
foreach ($fields as $field_name => $instance) {
  // Load up field info for this field.
  $field_info = field_info_field($field_name);

  // Get the type
  $type = $field_info['type'];
}
```